# Find continuous area without narrow bottlenecks using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1

I want to get the contours of a continues area, but without having very narrow places in the output.

The input image can look like this image (after applying the threshold):[image: Input image]

By just calling OpenCVs findContours method, I get following result:[image: Actual output]

My problem is that I don't want to have the narrow (white) peaks in the result. Just blurring the image will not work, because I must not include the black peak(s). So the wanted output should look like this green line: [image: Ideal output]

Is it possible the tell OpenCV (findContours) a minimum "thickness" of the area?

Comment: Why don't you use [morphological operations](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) to get rid of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Erosion](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) can be thought as adding the boundary pixels to the background. Thus, it gets rid of such narrow pieces in your input. However, since it distorts all the boundaries, you need to apply [dilation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) afterwards, to undo the effect of erosion on the actual boundary. The erosion+dilation process is called [opening](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).

The code portion below generates the desired output. Play with `k_size` according to your image size. Then apply `findContours`.

```
# Read and binarize the image
image = cv2.imread("test.png",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, im_th =cv2.threshold(image,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Set the kernel and perform opening
k_size = 7
kernel = np.ones((k_size,k_size),np.uint8)
opened = cv2.morphologyEx(im_th, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
cv2.imwrite("opened.png", opened)
```

The output:

[image: Opened output with no islands]

Answer (score 0):

Use erosion, followed by dilation with a small kernel before you do `findContours`. There's a special kind of operator in OpenCV that does just that, called [Opening](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html#opening) with `morphologyEx`

Something like this should work:

```
morphologyEx(src, dst, MORPH_OPEN, Mat());
```